# Backup up zone records using BIND in a BIND format

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

How do I get the DNS zone records from BIND in a BIND format file?

Is it possible to export those?

Comment: -1 - please specify if server that runs bind is under your control, and mention that you have 3000 domains in the question itself.

Comment: are zones dynamically updated ?

Answer (score 6):

Aside from.. copying the zone file?

Well, if you've got zone transfers enabled, then you can pull it with `dig` via a device that's authorized to do the transfer:

```
dig @nameserver axfr yourdomain.com
```

Comment: And if you have 3000 domains?

Answer (score 0):

you need access to the DNS server in case you cant do what Shane mentioned, your zones might be located as per in /etc/bind/named.conf, then simply tar -zcvf the dir.....

Comment: tar the dns directory and the zone files?

Comment: do you have access to the server?